# addAll or assign new value to Map when setState

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable like this:

```
LinkedHashMap _items = new LinkedHashMap();
```

With a web service I load other items (`tmpItems`) from the web and I need to add the items or assign them to the variable, depending on the value of the `page` variable.

If `page = 1`, I need to assign new items to `_items` variable, if `page > 1` I need to `addAll` new items to `_items` variable.

Right now I have:

```
setState(() {
    _items.addAll(tmpItems ?? []);
});
```

I need something like:

```
setState(() {
    _page > 1 ? _items.addAll(tmpItems ?? []) : _items = tmpItems;
});
```

But I know this code is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use an [`if` statement](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#if-and-else) for this purpose:

```dart
setState(() {
  if (_page > 1) {
    _items.addAll(tmpItems ?? []);
  } else {
    _items = tmpItems ?? [];
  }
});
```